# Reduce по массиву объектов. Не могу правильно составить. Суммирование внутри reduce если свойство объекта повторяется

Tags: javascript, объекты, ecmascript-6, filter, map-reduce

Есть массив объектов

```
 [
      {
        "id": 506,
        "NAME": "Алексей Морозов",
        "WELD_LENGTH": "1708",
        "SUM_WELD_LENGTH": 13664,
        "DATE": "03.08.2019",
        "DATE_TIMESTAMP": 1564779600,
        "QUANTITY": "8"
      },
      {
        "id": 508,
        "NAME": "Алексей Морозов",
        "WELD_LENGTH": "1013",
        "SUM_WELD_LENGTH": 1013,
        "DATE": "05.08.2019",
        "DATE_TIMESTAMP": 1564952400,
        "QUANTITY": "1"
      },
      {
        "id": 509,
        "NAME": "Алексей Морозов",
        "WELD_LENGTH": "3211",
        "SUM_WELD_LENGTH": 6422,
        "DATE": "05.08.2019",
        "DATE_TIMESTAMP": 1564952400,
        "QUANTITY": "2"
      },
      {
        "id": 510,
        "NAME": "Алексей Морозов",
        "WELD_LENGTH": "3130",
        "SUM_WELD_LENGTH": 6260,
        "DATE": "05.08.2019",
        "DATE_TIMESTAMP": 1564952400,
        "QUANTITY": "2"
      },
      {
        "id": 512,
        "NAME": "Алексей Морозов",
        "WELD_LENGTH": "1519",
        "SUM_WELD_LENGTH": 1519,
        "DATE": "05.08.2019",
        "DATE_TIMESTAMP": 1564952400,
        "QUANTITY": "1"
      },
      {
        "id": 513,
        "NAME": "Алексей Морозов",
        "WELD_LENGTH": "1022",
        "SUM_WELD_LENGTH": 4088,
        "DATE": "05.08.2019",
        "DATE_TIMESTAMP": 1564952400,
        "QUANTITY": "4"
      }
    ]
```

Хочу получить объект в котором на одну дату, например 05.08.2019 поле SUM_WELD_LENGTH имело бы общую сумму от всех записей(объектов) поля SUM_WELD_LENGTH. То есть на дату 05.08.2019, 1013+6422+6260+1519+4088 = 19302.
У меня получается что к этому 19302 значению суммируется еще и значение с предыдущей даты 03.08.2019.
Хочу получить массив вида:

```
{
  "03.08.2019": {
    "date": "03.08.2019",
    "val_sum_weld_length": 13664,
    "val_name": "Алексей Морозов"
  },
  "05.08.2019": {
    "date": "05.08.2019",
    "val_sum_weld_length": 32966, //Должно быть 19302 со всех записей с датой 05.08.2019
    "val_name": "Алексей Морозов"
  }
}
```

Мой код

```
    let sum = 0;
    let arr_date_for_label = rows_map.reduce(function(acc, currentValue, index, array){
        let val_name = currentValue['NAME'];
        let val_date = currentValue['DATE'];
        let val_sum_weld_length = currentValue['SUM_WELD_LENGTH'];

        acc[val_date] = {date: val_date, val_sum_weld_length: 0, val_name: val_name };

        //Если дата совпадает
        if (acc[val_date].date === val_date){
            sum += val_sum_weld_length;
            acc[val_date] = {date: val_date, val_sum_weld_length: sum, val_name: val_name};
        }

        return acc;
    }, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

Раз уж мы решили делать функционально при помощи reduce, то не будем мутировать `acc`, изменяя его поля. Потому что мутации противоречат правилам функционального кодирования.

Без мутаций код будет выглядет как-то так:

```js
const arr_date = rows_map.reduce(function (acc, currentValue) {
    if (!acc.hasOwnProperty(currentValue.DATE)) {
        return {
            ...acc,
            [currentValue.DATE]: {
                date: currentValue.DATE,
                val_sum_weld_length: currentValue.SUM_WELD_LENGTH,
                val_name: currentValue.NAME,
            },
        };
    }

    return {
        ...acc,
        [currentValue.DATE]: {
            ...acc[currentValue.DATE],
            val_sum_weld_length:
                acc[currentValue.DATE].val_sum_weld_length + currentValue.SUM_WELD_LENGTH,
        },
    };
}, {});
```

Для того чтоб понять что делается в коде, прийдётся разобраться с тем что такое spread operator. Еще рекомендую погуглить про мутациями (и почему их следует избегать).

Comment: еще такое небольшое наблюдение  по стилю кодирования: в последнее время в JS принято использовать `camelCase` для именования переменных.